Not able to access gcp firestore while using it from docker, Getting "'@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo"
docker run --rm gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/google-cloud-cli:stable sh -c "gcloud firestore databases list"
ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.databases.list) [role@firbase-accountXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission to access projects instance [kreditbee-stage] (or it may not exist): 
Request had insufficient authentication scopes. This command is authenticated as role@firbase-accountXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com which is the active account specified by the [core/account] property.
'@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: googleapis.com
  metadata:fir
    method: google.firestore.admin.v1.FirestoreAdmin.ListDatabases
    service: firestore.googleapis.com
  reason: ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT

If you are in a compute engine VM, it is likely that the specified scopes during VM creation are not enough to run this command.
See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam for more information about access scopes.
See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes for how to update access scopes of the VM.

image with the given error
Tried to run a docker and access firestore using gcp cli ,in VMs not getting able to access this getting some rpc error.
